# How can I use datetime in for loop?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I use `datetime` in **`for`** loop ?

There are two variables `duedate` and `returndate`, return date is current date and duedate is incremented by one day and is equal to returndate.

How can I use this in for loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use:

```
DateTime start = ...;
DateTime finish = ...;

for (DateTime x = start; x <= finish; x = x.AddDays(1))
{
   ... // use x
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(DateTime date=duedate;date.Date<DateTime.Now.Date;date=date.AddDays(1))
{
}
```

something like this

Answer (score 1):

It will be pretty straight. See below:

```
DateTime validFrom =  (DateTime)dtValidFrom.Value;

DateTime validTo =  (DateTime)dtValidTo.Value;

for (DateTime dt = validFrom; dt <= validTo; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
DateTime end = new DateTime();

for (DateTime start = new DateTime(); start < end; start.AddDays(1))
{
    //process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An other way:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime();
DateTime endval = new DateTime();
//It means it is 1 hour interval:
TimeSpan inctrementval = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);

for (DateTime t = start; t < endval; t += incrementval)
{
    //Your code will not reach endval
}
```

Or:

```
for (DateTime t = start; t <= endval; t += incrementval)
{
    //Your code will reach endval
}
```